# Woocommerce - Add another custom status so it will make the order "editable"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, add-filter

I created another custom statuses to wc statuses, and I want this status to leave the order "editable", so I found this code in the file `abstract-wc-order.php`:

```
public function is_editable() {
        return apply_filters( 'wc_order_is_editable', in_array( $this->get_status(), array( 'pending', 'on-hold', 'auto-draft', 'failed' ) ), $this );
    }
```

Now if I understand currently, I need to add my custom status to the array above, but I'm not really sure how to do this - to add my status to the above array by hooking the filter `wc_order_is_editable`, I will really appreciate to any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like this will work:

```
function so_39193164_is_editable( $editable, $order ) {
    if( $order->get_status() == 'your-new-status' ){
        $editable = true;
    }
    return $editable;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_is_editable', 'so_39193164_is_editable', 10, 2 );
```

If the order status is your new status then `$editable` will be true. If not, it will be whatever WooCommerce already decided in the `is_editable()` method.